# Why calling a query as a view takes lots of extra time to be executed?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, sql-view

Here is my query: (it takes `0.01` sec) to be executed:

```
SELECT `pos_transactions`.`id`, 
       `psps`.`name` psp_or_club_name, 
        businesses.discount, 
        shop_name, 
        businesses.city_id, 
       `amount`,
       `transaction_date`, 
       `psp_id` , 
       `business_id`, 
       'pos' as `name`, 
       `daily_percentage`
FROM `pos_transactions`       
JOIN `businesses` 
  ON `business_id` = `businesses`.`id`
JOIN `business_sub_categories` 
  ON `businesses`.`sub_category_id` = `business_sub_categories`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `psps`  
  ON `psp_id` = `psps`.`id`

UNION ALL

SELECT `club_transactions`.`id`, 
       `clubs`.`name_fa`,
        psp_or_club_name, 
        businesses.discount,
        shop_name, 
        businesses.city_id,
       `amount`,
       `transaction_date`,
       `club_transactions`.`club_id` as `psp_id` ,
       `business_id`, 
       'club' as `name`, 
       `daily_percentage` 
FROM `club_transactions`
JOIN `businesses` 
  ON `business_id` = `businesses`.`id`
JOIN `business_sub_categories` 
  ON `businesses`.`sub_category_id` = `business_sub_categories`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `clubs`  
  ON `club_transactions`.`club_id` = `clubs`.`id`
where `club_transactions`.`status` = "paid"
```

I need to make a `view` of it and them call it in different places. So I create the view this way:

```
CREATE VIEW myview AS ( <query above> )
```

And then use it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM myview
```

but it takes `3` sec to be executed. Why really? And how can I optimize it?

---

And here is the result of `EXPLAIN`:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VSds.png)

Comment: You need to create proper indexes in the tables for the columns.

Comment: @Mansoor Well, needed indexes are created as well . Since the query executes in about `0.1` sec that is acceptable for me. The current issue is it takes lots of time when I make a `view` of it.

Comment: In that case can you also add query plan? `explain analyze select * from myview`

Comment: And also what all indexes you've added?

Comment: @Mansoor The result of `explain` added

Comment: If you've MySQL 8.0.18 or greater, please run `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` instead of `EXPLAIN`. `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` will run the query and gives you exact time on each step

Answer (score 1):

- 3 sec for 280K rows -- Not bad.
- 0.01 sec for 280K rows -- sounds like the Query cache is turned on and it looked up the result without actually evaluating it.  Re-time it after adding `SQL_NO_CACHE` immediately after each `SELECT`.
- The first `SELECT` has no filtering, so it is obligated to fetch 280K rows.
- `pos_transactions` and `club_transactions` seem to be nearly identical.  I suggest you combine them into a single `transactions` table.  That will probably help the Optimizer do a better job.

To discuss further, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table, the table sizes.

**The explanation**

The 0.01 sec is bogus!  The UI appended `LIMIT 24` onto the query before running it.  That let it stop before doing all the work, hence ran quite fast.

Comment: I tested, it is not used the cache and still fast even by using `SQL_NO_CACHE`. Please take a look at [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3GQM.jpg)

Comment: Hmmm...  This is perhaps the only case where showing an _image_ (instead of text) helped solve the mystery.  (I added to my Answer.)

Answer (score 0):

One potential cause is the [query cache](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html), try [disabling](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/mysql-reference-manual/0596002653/ch06s09.html) it to see if it solves the issue.
Another cause would be that the [view optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-table-optimization.html) is leading to using temp tables which causes slowness.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've index on

- `pos_transactions.business_id`
- `businesses.sub_category_id`
- `pos_transactions.psp_id`
- `club_transactions.business_id`
- `club_transactions.status`

If you've indexes. You can try running [ANALYZE TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/analyze-table.html) **table_names** on tables to update table statistics